# How to verify if email exists in two seperate documents of mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have two models, patients and doctors. When the user signs in, be it the doctor or patient, there is only one route which runs the login function of the backend. But what I fail to understand is how to query such that it searches in both collections of patients and doctors by using single query.

This is the doctor model:

```
const doctorSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  practitionerLicense: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Doctor = mongoose.model("doctors", doctorSchema);
```

And the patient model:

```
const patientSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Patient = mongoose.model("patient", patientSchema);
```

Now I want something like the following pseudo code where users could be like a base class or something.

```
Users.findOne({email}).then(...)
```

I went through many other similar questions but saw methods like populate which I believe would not suit my case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your patient and doctor schemas are almost same except the practitionerLicense field.

So instead of two different schemas, I would create a common user schema with an additional role field like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  practitionerLicense: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["patient", "doctor"],
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

Note that I also set practitionerLicense's required option to false.

This way you can use a common user login form and route.

Your register route and register form in React can also be common, if you could verify if a user enters a practitioner license, and you can validate it using an API if there is such an API.

If that is not possible, your register routes and register components must be different for patient and doctor. When a user  registers in patient register form, you can set role to patient. And when a user registers in doctor register form, you can set role to doctor.

Comment: I get what you say but still if i want two seperate models rather than making one user model then how to i solve this problem. Doesn't mongoose provide with some kind of method to traverse two tables in one query?

Comment: @Emma there may an alternative solution using a third schema for only email and password.
Does it suits you?  But I still think using a common schema is the best solution for this scenario.

Comment: I also have separate profile models for both patients and doctors. If for instance I use your approach, wont connecting all those be difficult?

Comment: @Emma if the profile data also similar you can also use a common profile model. If not possible, there is always solution with mongoose populate.

Comment: oh alright! Just one thing more if now I m using one model user then how to write enum value in query. Can you please write a sample query so i get an idea.

Comment: Such as `Users.findOne({email}).then(...)` then where do i check for enum

Comment: @Emma role field type is String, so you can use it like other String type fields. Enum means it can only accept those values.

Comment: @Emma you can use like this: Users.findOne({role: "patient"})...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204060/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-emma).